# Livecharts change default legend

Tags: wpf, livecharts

Here is my problem.

I am using LiveCharts to display some data.
Everything fine until showing the legend which represents all the data displayed.

[chart with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfPbH.png)

Is it possibile to show a legend based on for example color(Stroke) or DefaultGeometries?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Diego

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a little late but I was looking to do something similar, so here is what I was able to come up with.

You would need to create a new collection and follow the example for [Live Charts Energy Predictions](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Energy%20Predictions).

First you need to set the LegendLocation="None" for the Chart

```
<wpf:CartesianChart Hoverable="False" DataTooltip="{x:Null}" DisableAnimations="True" LegendLocation="None" Series="{Binding AllSeries, ElementName=FastGraphRoot}">
```

New Legend Code (part that matters in .xaml):

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" MinHeight="250" ItemsSource="{Binding AllSeriesGroupByName, ElementName=FastGraphRoot}" Panel.ZIndex="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:LineSeries}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                           Foreground="{Binding Stroke}"
                           FontSize="24"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

The Binded list would come from the original series but grouped, I have used a property for this:

```
private SeriesCollection _allSeriesGroupByName = new SeriesCollection();
public SeriesCollection AllSeriesGroupByName { get { return _allSeriesGroupByName; } set { _allSeriesGroupByName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

you could fill it simply with this code(or anything else you think is faster):

```
var col = collection.GroupBy(g => ((LineSeries)g).Stroke).Select(p => p.First());
AllSeriesGroupByName = new SeriesCollection();
foreach (var c in col)
{
    AllSeriesGroupByName.Add(c);
}
```